# What is the differencen between ccTouchesEnded and ccTouchEnded

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm learning cocos2d-x. Following the tutorial I found that ccTouchesEnded works perfectly in linux (and windows) but when I replace by ccTouchEnded the event isn't detected anymore.

What are differences between this two functions? And why one is detected and the other isn't.

Taking the HelloWorld project sample as a base, I add the following lines in init()

this->setTouchEnabled(true);
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::updateGame));

Also, add this method to my code:

```
void HelloWorld::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
    // TouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this,0,true);
    Director::getInstance()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this,0);
}
```

Then if I add ccTouchesEnded like this:

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(Set* touches, Event* event)
{
    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    Touch* touch = static_cast<Touch*>( touches->anyObject() );
    Point location = touch->getLocation();

    log("++++++++after  x:%f, y:%f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

it works perfectly but if I use ccTouchEnded as:

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    Point location = touch->getLocation();

    log("++++++++after  x:%f, y:%f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

The events aren't fired.

Any help is welcome
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. The `ccTouchesEnded` version handles multiple touches (as the name implies) so it's a little more difficult to work with, but also more powerful. Use this method if you're dealing with more than one touch, like pinch zooming or rotating.

The `ccTouchEnded` version is just looking at one touch. This is simpler to use, since you don't have to break apart the events yourself.

Both of these methods are part of larger sets of similar methods:

(Standard)

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and

(Targeted)

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@optional
// touch updates:
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You need to be consistent in your use of these. If you start with `ccTouchesBegan` you need to end with `ccTouchesEnded`. Likewise, if you start with `ccTouchBegan` you'd check for moves with `ccTouchMoved` and ended with `ccTouchEnded`.

You can learn more about [Targeted vs Standard touch delegates here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3atouchdelegates?s%5B%5D=targeted&s%5B%5D=standard)

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't explain why in my application in windows ccTouchesEnded is called (so the event is fired) but ccTouchEnded don't

Comment: You didn't ask why it doesn't work for you (and you don't include enough information to answer that anyway), you asked what the difference is. But it's probably as I said "*You need to be consistent in your use of these*" If you start looking for events with one type of delegate, you need to finish looking with that type of delegate. I've told you how they're different, it's up to you to apply that to why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Byte56, wasn't my intention to be rude. English is not my mother language. I'm adding additional information about the case, but it it seems very simple...

Comment: I don't intend to be rude either, I'm just stating what I think are the facts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `void CCLayer::setTouchMode(ccTouchesMode mode)` to change the touch event mode.

```
typedef enum {
  kCCTouchesAllAtOnce,
  kCCTouchesOneByOne,
} ccTouchesMode;
```

According to my understanding, the touch event will only be invoked in either mode of the two. And by default, it is *AllAtOnce*.